# Consider the second-order equation $ \displaystyle \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+3\frac{dy}{dt}+2y=0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the second-order equation
$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+3\frac{dy}{dt}+2y=0 $$
Let $v$ be a new variable that represents $ \frac{dy}{dt}$ and reduce reduce this equation to a first-order system in terms of $y$ and $v$. Find the solution to this system that satisfies the initial condition $(y(0),v(0))=(1,-2)$

What will be $y(t)$?

What will be $v(t)$?

I assume that I can rewrite the expression $ \frac{dy}{dt}$ as $v$ so I get that

$ \displaystyle \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+3v+2y=0 $ is it the good way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of the ODE is:
$$y(t)=C_1e^{-2t}+C_2e^{-t}$$
with your initial conditions you get:
$$y(t)=e^{-2t}$$
and so: $\dot{y}(t)=-2e^{-2t}$

Answer (score 3):

This solution is only a hint, since that question is some homework.

> $ \displaystyle \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+3v+2y=0 $ is it the good way?

The task states, that you should reformulate the equation into a system of first order ODEs. So there should be no second derivative any more.

As you stated, you can define:
$$ v:= \frac{d}{dt}y$$

How can you now replace $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}y$ using $v$?

The system of order one should look like
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}y &= ϕ(t, y, v, y', v') \\
\frac{d}{dt}v &= ψ(t, y, v, y', v') \\
\end{align*}
with both $ϕ$ and $ψ$ *not* depending on second order derivatives.

Comment: This is the best answer and seeks to hint at a solution for the OPs actual question, +1.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+3\frac{dy}{dt}+2y-0$$

Notice that is this a second order homogeneous differential equation with constant coefficients.

$1,3,2$

We can use the Method of auxiliary equation to solve it.

$$y=e^{mt}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=me^{mt}$$

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=m^2e^{mt}$$

Substitute this into the differentia equation we then have

$$m^2e^{mt}+3me^{mt}+2e^{mt}=0$$

Provided $e^{mt}\neq 0$

$$m^2+3m+2=0$$

$$(m+1)(m+2)=0$$

$m=-1,-2$

The fundamental set of solution is then

$$y=c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^{-2t}$$

where $c_1,c_2$ are constants.

Hope that you can take it from here.